# Excel non contiguous named range values evaluate to #VALUE, causes SUMIF to fail

Tags: excel, sumifs, named-ranges

All of my named ranges refer to valid cell references, but the range Values come up as null (see Name Manager in photo). This causes the SUMIF function I wish to apply =SUMIF(RangeofID_Codes, ID_Code, RangeOfValues).

I have tried evaluating the criteria against the source (budget codes on bottom left) and they evaluate to TRUE, the ranges have the same number of values (but are non contiguous), but cannot get ranges to check against eachother. I've noticed there are no brackets around the cell references to the non contiguous cells in the RefersTo field for each named range - is this the issue? If so, how do I correct that? Please help, this should be so easy!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58plH.png)

Comment: Without knowing your references it'd difficult to pin point the issue. Perhaps copy the relevant sheets (with dummy data) into a google sheet and share it? 

Also 2 tips: 
- Don't share production data online (if your taking a screenshot at least fill it with dummy data) 
- If you do share prod data, remove your name from the shot to protect your own amenity

Comment: I'm certainly not going to retype your data so either generate a [mcve], post a link to a redacted google-sheet or use the [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-D64C47F3-AAFD-4B2E-AE5D-C16EE3180576) with [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) or [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to sum every second row that matches.

Comment: @user3240704 thanks for your concern with privacy but this is sample date - tying to get the budget template to work before inputting production data. I did not realize that my name appreared though, so thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Jeeped could you please elaborate on the method you've described? is it a known means of comparing non contiguous ranges against eachother? I understand the individual methods but not how they might combine to resolve this issue.

Comment: Supply a [mcve] that I don't have to retype.

Comment: @Jeeped The issue is not replicable in Google Sheets because Sheets does not allow you to name a non contiguous range. See my "answer" below for a photo of the two ranges being used by the SUMIF function. If this is not sufficient then I can try to send a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example in .xls format, which I have but just cannot replicated in Sheets due to the non contiguity issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying cells within your ranges are calculations, I would update them so that they return either blanks or zeros.

Comment: The underlying cells are not calculations but rather simple input values. I've manually entered zeroes in all blank cells and confirmed that they are of the same data type - the type matches and I've tested each cell individually to confirm that they should return a match. They breakdown occurs not from matching individual cells but rather in attempting to compares the two non contiguous ranges.